# Add user defined object to list of objects only if it's new

Tags: python

I have a list of user defined objects (all of the same type) and I need to write a function that will add additional items of the same class to the list only if the item is not already in the list. The fake code looks like this:

```
object_list = [object1, object2]

def some_func(new_object):
    if new_object not in object_list:
        object_list.append(new_object)
```

The class has a number of attributes, none of which are necessarily unique to an instance.

Comment: Does the object have an identifier based on which you're identifying it is the same?

Comment: Does that class implement hashcode and equals methods in a meaningful way? If so, you could just use an (ordered) dict to quickly check if it is already contained in O(1) and if not, add it with some arbitrary value.

Comment: *For user-defined classes which define the __contains__() method, x in y returns True if y.__contains__(x) returns a true value, and False otherwise.  For user-defined classes which do not define __contains__() but do define __iter__(), x in y is True if some value z, for which the expression x is z or x == z is true, is produced while iterating over y. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if in raised that exception.* https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: i.e. `in` should should if `__eq__` defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the __eq__ method should solve the problem
[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**eq**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    """Overrides the default implementation"""
    if not isinstance(other, DefinedClass):
        return NotImplemented
    # comparison logic
    return self.id1 == other.id1 && self.id2 == other.id2
```